# Problems turning USB-A mouse dongle to USB-C

Tags: usb, soldering, usb-device, usb-c, usb-host

today I was trying to turn my old USB-A mouse receiver to an USB-C mouse receiver.
I was using an USB-C plug of an old broken USB-C to USB-A/Ethernet-Adapter (similar to the one in the picture), it had the 4 USB wires for 5V, Ground, Data+, Data- .

[image: Text]

Firstly I was trying to solder the USB-C plug to a wired USB-A mouse and it worked perfectly and the laptop instantly recognized the mouse. Then I've tried to solder it to my wireless mouse receiver and the laptop doesn't recognize the mouse (via USB-A its still working).
What could be the problem, anyone have an idea? (I've also checked if electricity flows through the wires, it does)

[image: Text]
[image: Text]

I hope you guys could help me, thank you!

Comment: That is not possible.

Comment: I'm really not in into this topic, but I can't understant why it isn possible - because with a normal usb mouse it already worked

Comment: The solder job is botched, you have cold joints, naked wire, melted cables... If you have never soldered anything before, start out with through hole components while you learn.

Comment: Do you have a pull-down on CC-pin(s)?